# How to pull RSS feed of all Stack Overflow jobs in particular city?

Tags: rss

I wish to pull an RSS feed of all the Stack Overflow jobs for a particular city.
I know [the link to get all of them](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed),
but how do I get all from only Sydney for example?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is specifically the Stack Exchange API, which is off topic on Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: oh ok. i didnt know that. does it belong somewhere else?

Comment: If it's **only** about how to use actual Stack Exchange tools (as in this instance), it's probably more suitable for [metase], as it's about the Stack Exchange network. However, if you're asking about _why_ your code doesn't work (and it's unlikely it's a bug with their code), even if it incorporates Stack Exchange code, it's for Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a `location` parameter:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?location=sydney
```

Comment: thanks heaps. i mustve overlooked this

Answer (score 6):

Go to the jobs page and fill in whatever criteria yoy want in the search box in the top right. Click search, and then click the small RSS icon above the search box.

Look closely at the URL - you should see enough there to answer your question.

As an example:

Jobs within 20 miles of Sydney:

```
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed?location=sydney&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles
```